# MYSQL - Return pattern that is matched against

Tags: python, mysql

In the below example query I'm selecting a phrase(e.g. "I like dogs") where it matches to at least one entry in a set of keywords (e.g. "dogs | cats"). My question is whether it is possible to extract the keyword(s) that the phrase matches to. So, in the above "dogs" is returned but if the phrase was "I Like dogs and cats" "dogs" and "cats" is returned.

select phrase from animals where phrase REGEXP (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(kw SEPARATOR '|') from
 keywords )

Comment: You can use a bunch of UNIONs, or perhaps a CASE statement, in older versions, but it's not very elegant

Answer (score 1):

You can do this fairly easily in MySQL 8+ with `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(input, '^.*\\bI like (dogs|cats)\\b.*$', '$1') AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: @Strawberry This really doesn't answer the full question, but the full question really requires a text parser; way out of scope for what a database is designed for.